# Como ocultar contenido de la carpeta assets en android studio?

Tags: android-studio

Buen dia, tengo unos archivos .html en la carpeta assets pero no se como ocultarlos ya que con cualquier app o pagina para descomprimir apk esos archivos los muestra sin problemas, hay alguna manera de codificarlos o ocultar todo lo que se tiene en assets?

Comment: Recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigaste a tu pregunta, para recibir mejores respuestas, revisar [ak], saludos.